What is the Best Practice to installing Python Dependencies for small scale Local Projects (Mac)
I have a Homebrew install of python3.13. I want to update pip and install numpy but if I try pip3.13 install numpy or python3.13 -m pip install --upgrade pip I get an error:
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
    xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a Python library that isn't in Homebrew,
    use a virtual environment:

    python3 -m venv path/to/venv
    source path/to/venv/bin/activate
    python3 -m pip install xyz

    If you wish to install a Python application that isn't in Homebrew,
    it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. You can install pipx with

    brew install pipx

    You may restore the old behavior of pip by passing
    the '--break-system-packages' flag to pip, or by adding
    'break-system-packages = true' to your pip.conf file. The latter
    will permanently disable this error.

    If you disable this error, we STRONGLY recommend that you additionally
    pass the '--user' flag to pip, or set 'user = true' in your pip.conf
    file. Failure to do this can result in a broken Homebrew installation.

    Read more about this behavior here: <https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/>

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification. 

I want to stop this happening by preventing Homebrew from Externally Managing python. As has been suggested I probably dont want to use Homebrew anymore, thus the title. What is the BEST practice for installing python and projects for personal usage? (if the answer is virtual environments, can you try to explain how this works in practice, i.e. when I am in a random directory and want to open a python file to do a thing, I don't want to have to start a venv session (to me that seems cumbersome) so how might I set a default venv that is used when the user calls python.)

"now it seems like Homebrew wants to manage my python packages" — How'd you conclude that?

Homebrew can manage packages, and does so for the  benefit of its own Python applications. There's no reason you need to use them for your own projects.

I say this as the only reason for my home-brew installed python to be marked as Externally Managed is if it is managing it and stopping me from

All your quick-and-dirty one-offs can simply use the same "global" virtual env, separate from your project-specific virtual envs.

From what I understood a virtual env was a local "installation" python and all its packages that was locked down to a direactory or project. What would a "global" virtual env mean and how is that different to an ordinary install of python (I specifically dont want to have to run some venv ... type of command every time I want to use python for just doing s tiny bumpy calculation)

You may also want to read Homebrew Python is Not For You (the original seems to be missing; this is a link to a Internet Archive snapshot from October 2024).

Just brew install python, then python3 -m pip install numpy. That installs numpy into your global package directory, and it's generally available anytime you launch python3. For more specific projects, create venvs and install specific packages in it.

How is any virtual environment different from an ordinary install? It shares an executable, but the library (specifically, the site-packages) is specific to it. For example, I have generic Python 3.11 and Python 3.12 virtual environments on my machine with a hodgepodge of packages installed in each for testing SO answers. (Which reminds me, I need to create a similar Python 3.13 venv one of these days.) Basically, the ordinary installation has no additional packages installed to it, and exists only to use as the base for one or more virtual environments.

Please clarify when/where/how exactly you're encountering "the Externally Managed Enviornments error". I'm not familiar with that, and I've installed a lot of Python via brew…

That link is a very interesting read, annoying though it may be I understand the idea behind it and may force me off homebrew for python

I stopped using Homebrew a while ago; I just jump back and forth between a python.org-installed version and using Nix.

When I run python3.13 -m pip install numpy I get the error message detailed https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/externally-managed-environments/ : python3.13 is a home-brew python install. Currently my python3 is set to 9.6 for what ever reason (I have just always used python3.x and pip3.x so never noticed this)

To get back on track, what then is the best practice for having some "global" venv

These days, I'd just let https://docs.astral.sh/uv/ manage things. uv run foo.py will run foo.py in a venv, and you can even specify requirements within foo.py.

Hmm looks interesting, but I would prefer a default python way to understand how it is meant to be done

This seems to have had some discussion on the Homebrew page. They seem to more or less agree with @chepner

After going through the discussions on the Hombrew page and PEP I have come to the conclusion that python via Homebrew is not for me. Instead pyenv seems to be the best way forward, and should in my opinion be the default way for anyone working with a non-system version of python. The set up is:

brew install pyenv or some alternative install.
Add ~/.pyenv to the path via adding export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH" to .bashrc / .zshrc (read pyenv init)
pyenv install X.X to install a fresh version of pythonX.X
pyenv global X.X to see the current default python, run python --version to check this (requires a shell restart)

I would have thought 2. was done by Homebrew. This is a little bit more involved than running brew install python@X.X but unless the maintainers decide on another implementation of this Externally Managed Environment, the Homebrew version of python should be avoided by all.
It seems the main thought process is that the python versions Homebrew will maintain are primarily for the maintenance of Homebrew packages, and can also be used by the user. This means they have implemented a default roadblock to installing packages via pip. While I have my reservations of this, and mostly agree with Matthew Brett on that page, I was looking for a solution not arguments, and am happy to settle with pyenv
